# Disable of Page Break display in excel sheet after printing

Tags: vba, excel

I have added the pagebreaks between different charts in a excel sheet ,and disabled the display of pagebreaks by using a VBA code. But after printing the charts ,pagebreaks are displayed in a excel sheet .
please help me to disable the page breaks display even after printing the charts in VBA.

I have used this code to insert the pagebreaks and disable the display of page breaks

```
 newch.ResetAllPageBreaks
    newch.Rows(40).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    newch.Rows(71).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    newch.Rows(103).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    newch.Rows(135).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

    pageBreakcol = LastCol + 10
    alpha = Col_Letter(CInt(pageBreakcol))
    newch.Columns(alpha).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

    'vbreak

    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        newch.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView 

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With newch.PageSetup

            .CenterHorizontally = True
          .CenterVertically = True
        End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    newch.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

Comment: Instead of `ActiveSheet`, you might wanna try `Worksheet("name").DisplayPageBreaks = False`. If this does not work, you should post other relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Thank you ! but  same problem repeated .

Comment: You have to be more precise

Comment: Are the charts part of a worksheet, or are they on their own tab?

Comment: If you're inserting page breaks, they are probably going to display.  Try **not** inserting page breaks.  Also, **Please Share Your Code** as well as a screenshot showing the page breaks you are referring to.

Comment: yes charts are part of a worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If you add your own page breaks (for example, with [`HPageBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hpagebreak-object-excel) or [`VPageBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/vpagebreak-object-excel), or with the [`Chart.PageSetup` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/chart-pagesetup-property-excel)), it will **override** the 'ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False' setting.

**Additionally, from the documentation:**

> If you add a page break that does not intersect the print area, then the newly-added [**HPageBreak**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hpagebreak-object-excel) object will not appear in the [**HPageBreaks**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hpagebreaks-object-excel) collection for the print area. The contents of the collection may change if the print area is resized or redefined.

<sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hpagebreaks-object-excel))</sup>

> If you add a page break that does not intersect the print area, then the newly-added **[VPageBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/vpagebreak-object-excel)** object will not appear in the **[VPageBreaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/vpagebreaks-object-excel)** collection for the print area. The contents of the collection may change if the print area is resized or redefined.
>
> - For an automatic print area, the **VPageBreaks** property applies only to the page breaks within the print area.
> - For a user-defined print area of the same range, the **VPageBreaks** property applies to all of the page breaks.

<sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/vpagebreaks-object-excel))</sup>

Depending on what you're doing, the [`PageSetup.PrintArea` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/pagesetup-printarea-property-excel) and [`FitToPages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-fittopagestall-property-excel) properties might be better suited.

Comment: Thank you ! but I m not able to resolve this issue ,please help me